# Numerical solution of integral equation

Tags: integral-equations

I am trying to solve this integral equation numerically:

$$f(x)=\int_a^b \frac{g(x)\,f(x)}{\sqrt{h(x)^2+f(x)^2}}\, dx$$

where $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are known functions, and the limits of integration are given by two constants, $a$ and $b$.

Please answer—it is an emergency.

Comment: Please, read the documentation.

Comment: What is a racine? You should at least familiarize yourself with basic *Matmematica* coding practice before asking questions. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html

Comment: @mohammed Bendacha  Use Sqrt[...] instead of racine (frensh for Sqrt)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software

Comment: Look, your integral is a constant, rather that a function of x. It cannot be equal to f(x).

Comment: so the limits of integral is given 0 to x

Comment: Go ahead and edit the question with the correct limits, a mathematica code formatted version of the expression, and examples for your g,h functions.  I'd suggest you also search this site for related questions.  (I will say more often than not the term "integral equation" is used incorrectly, yours actually is an integral equation (with the correct limits that is )